# Setting DATABASE_URL as an environmental variable using Play Framework 2.5.X on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, ide, environment-variables

I am using PlayFramework 2.5.X

In my Application.conf file I have :

```
#local DB
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
```

I am also using eclipse.
I am trying to edit the DATABASE_URL variable so I can test against my own db.
I know I go to Run > Run configurations > [From here Set Environmental Variables]

But which tab should I be looking at, Eclipse Configurations or Java Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play allows to use different configuration file for tests. In the test configuration file you can assign different value for any property, existing in *application.conf*. So, in tests configuration you can set different DB properties.

1. Create file *test.conf* under the *conf* folder (any other name/location is OK).
2. Put the test configuration file name into build.sbt:
   javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
3. Add content into the *test.conf*.

When you run sbt test, the sbt will take configuration file for tests.
If ytou are running tests from eclipse, add to the test run configuration VM argument -Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf

Example of test.conf below inherits all the properties, which are defined in the *application.conf*. It redefines the default db connection properties: h2 db instead of mySql, defined in the *application.conf*.

```
    include "application.conf"
    db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
    db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
    db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
    jpa.default=testPersistenceUnit
```